# Set next/previous weekday

Tags: bash

With following code I can roll day in Linux back and forth.

```
date -s 'tomorrow'
date -s 'yesterday'
```

I would like to do the same but skip weekends.

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Comment: Why setting the date permanently? You can use `-d` instead

Comment: I need to mimic 'changing the day' event for our automation tests. Application has logic to execute for 'next day' we want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [[ $( date +%u ) = 5 ]] ; then date --set="+3 days" ; else date --set="+1 days" ; fi
if [[ $( date +%u ) = 1 ]] ; then date --set="-3 days" ; else date --set="-1 days" ; fi
```

Answer (score 3):

The following gives you next working day (for `bash`):

```
if [[ $( date +%u ) -eq 5 ]] ; then date --date="next Monday" ; else date --date="next day" ; fi
```

Comment: I know we're not on codegolf, but I think this is just too ugly not to be shared : `date --date="next $([[ $( date +%u ) -eq 5 ]] && echo "Mon")day"`

Comment: you should check dow = 5 or 6

Comment: Yep. Missed that. Actually `> 4` would be enough

Comment: As long as we're golfing: `printf +%dday\\n 1 2 3|date -f-|grep -v ^S` (Change the `+` to `-- -` if you want the previous workday. Disclaimer: doesn't work with holidays or non-English locales.)

Comment: what about previous?

Comment: unlike `next day`, `next Monday` trancates hours

Answer (score 2):

This script sets the day to the next weekday. Before forewarned that these scripts strip out the time of day when jumping over the weekend. Also, they are not portable to limited shells like busybox.

```
week_day=$(date +%w) #get the week day as a number from 0
if [[ $week_day == 5 || $week_day == 6 ]] #check to see if it is Fri or Sat
then date -s 'next monday' #if it is Fri or Sat, the set day to next monday
else date -s tomorrow #it is a different day of the week, go to the next day
fi
```

The last week day

```
week_day=$(date +%w) #get the week day as a number from 0 to 6 starting with 0 as Sunday
if [[ $week_day == 0 || $week_day == 1 ]] #check to see if it is Sun or Mon 
then date -s 'last friday' #if it is Sun or Mon, the set day to last friday
else date -s yesterday #it is a different day of the week, go to yesterday
fi
```